# Task scheduler terminates completed task

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, task-scheduler

I am running a task using the Task Scheduler on a Windows Server 2012 R2 server.  Today I was examining the task's history.  My task completed successfully.

```
Task Scheduler successfully finished "{a17b1690-5381-4163-a7e5-ab01af11a18e}" instance of the "MyTask" task for user "MyUsername".
```

However, I noticed that the event following that task's completion was in the "Task terminated" category.

```
Task Scheduler terminated "{a17b1690-5381-4163-a7e5-ab01af11a18e}"  instance of the "MyTask"  task.
```

I have been trying to figure what caused this.  I do have the following setting checked:

```
If the running task does not end when requested, force it to stop.
```

Could this be why the Task Scheduler terminated the task?  I thought the task was done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm almost certain those two log entries are related and they match up with the configuration setting you have.

I would look at the application configuration to see why it's taking longer than excepted, if its taking as long as you expect, consider tweaking the settings to allow it to run for longer.